# Oracle SQL last n records

Tags: sql, oracle

i have read tons of articles regarding last n records in Oracle SQL by using rownum functionality, but on my case it does not give me the correct rows.

I have 3 columns in my table: 1) message (varchar), mes_date (date) and mes_time (varchar2).

Inside lets say there is 3 records:

```
Hello world | 20-OCT-14 | 23:50
World Hello | 21-OCT-14 | 02:32
Hello Hello | 20-OCT-14 | 23:52
```

I want to get the last 2 records ordered by its date and time (first row the oldest, and second the newest date/time)

i am using this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT message 
          FROM messages 
         ORDER 
            BY MES_DATE, MES_TIME DESC
       ) 
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 2 ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC;
```

Instead of getting row #3 as first and as second row #2 i get row #1 and then row #3

What should i do to get the older dates/times on top follow by the newest?

Comment: Can you post the results of "select to_char(mes_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from messages where rownum < 3" ? a date data-structure holds the hour in it... and I hope you actually store it in there, and than your life would be easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe that helps:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT message,
               mes_date,
               mes_time,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(mes_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || mes_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DESC) rank
          FROM messages 
       ) 
  WHERE rank <= 2
  ORDER 
     BY rank
```

Comment: By this way i get the oldest 2 rows: 23:50, 23:52 only

Comment: Append a DESC after the ORDER BY expression in the analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry to disappoint - but in Oracle there's no such thing as "the last two records".

The table structure does not allocate data at the end, and does not keep a visible property of time (the only time being held is for the sole purpose of "flashback queries" - supplying results as of point in time, such as the time the query started...).

The last inserted record is not something you can query using the database.

What can you do? You can create a trigger that orders the inserted records using a sequence, and select based on it (so `SELECT  * from (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY seq DESC) where rownum < 3`) - that will assure order only if the sequence CACHE value is 1.

Notice that if the column that contains the message date does not have many events in a second, you can use that column, as the other solution suggested - e.g. if you have more than 2 events that arrive in a second, the query above will give you random two records, and not the actual last two.

AGAIN - Oracle will not be queryable for the last two rows inserted since its data structure do not managed orders of inserts, and the ordering you see when running "SELECT *" is independent of the actual inserts in some specific cases.

If you have any questions regarding any part of this answer - post it down here, and I'll focus on explaining it in more depth.

Comment: There is. You could use the date on which OP sorts, so there is a clear definition of 'last'.

Comment: NO, you cannot use ROWID. read about the structure of ROWID. ROWID is generated for each query, and does not imply time of inserts, but order of querying

Comment: Okay. What about the `date` OP uses?

Comment: The problem is that Oracle does not hold any information that implies on ordering of inserts. The database is there to store stuff efficiently.. if you want to add to the data something that implies order, you have to do it manually - add a column with order of inserts (using a sequence) using a DATE or a TIMESTAMP if the resolution of messages assures no more than two records will fall into the same time-slot (if you need ordering). Oracle puts it on the database architecture to solve application needs, Oracle will manage the storage of whatever you need to store..

Comment: But this is enough, right? `BY MES_DATE, MES_TIME DESC`

Comment: i don't want to get the last 2 INSERTED records, but the last 2 records of my selection. so if i do a selection and get  2-1-3. with the last 2 to get only 1-3.

Comment: Oh, OK, from what I read initially - I thought you expect the last two records. Can you post the results for the query I posted above? the DATE datastructure contains time, I think you just don't see it, and hopefully in this case you hold it in there, and than you can make your query much more efficient...

Comment: The query is "select to_char(mes_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from messages where rownum < 3"

Comment: I got it correct finally by using DirkNM's method. But here is the results of your query: 1) 10/20/2014 00:00:00 and 2) 10/21/2014 00:00:00

Comment: Yeah, you don't hold time there... Derek's solution is correct, for what you stated - but remember - if you have 3 records which have a date and time which are the same - you will get random 2 out of the 3 relevant records, and not the last two inserted :) by the way - you can make the query "lighter" by removing the analytic function from the query, so if you'll have performance issues due to the rank, there's a way to optimize this query. (for optimizing it you'd might need to add a function based index though)

Comment: thanks for the tips :) i will only show 7-8 records on screen with messages and the inserts will be a minimum 1 minute apart (manually typing) so i believe will not have any performance issues.

Comment: I'm always worried about performance...
If you'll have performance issues, hit us back :) there's always a way to improve performance... GOOD LUCK!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for my problem that I found and worked.

**Table Structure:**
[image]

I wanted to have a query to get last 4 records based on year in desc order.

**Solution I found**

```html
SELECT year, lock_status
    FROM (SELECT YEAR,
                 LOCK_STATUS,
                 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY YEAR DESC)     RANK
            FROM CONTROL_YEAR_UPLOAD_SETTINGS)
   WHERE RANK <= 3
ORDER BY RANK
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table
minus
select * from table
where rownum<=(select count(*) from table)-n
```

Comment: Hi, please provide an explanation of your code (even inline comments help).

Comment: In Oracle, MINUS operator is used to return all rows in the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement..ROWNUM is used to restrict number of records .. Let's say your table has 15 records and you want to get last 5 records.So,the first query will return all 15 records and second query will return first 10 records .Hence,Minus operator will return last five records..Hope It helps.

Comment: Hi, if you want to add to your answer, please [edit] it.

Comment: This can't work in case if column is having some year data and user is expecting in ascending or descending order based on year column. This will have an impact based on inserted record time.